# vba code add a character to a row based on the value of another one

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro to add a dot (.) at the end of the product name if the Stock account is equal to "Amaysim - Woolworths".

So far I've created the code below but I do not know how to add just the dot instead of changing the cell value next to "Amaysim - Woolworths"

```
Option Explicit

    Public Sub Woolworths_update()

    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange

        If ActiveSheet.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then .AutoFilter
           .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Amaysim - Woolworths"

           'I know I need to change something on the following line code but I do not know how to do it'
            .Columns(3).Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1) = "1/1/2010"
            .AutoFilter

        End With

    End Sub
```

[This is a sample of the report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvIFT.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below has been tested and works. Note that I cleaned the code up a bit for best practices.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Woolworths_update()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("myName") 'adjust to your sheet

    With ws

        .UsedRange.AutoFilter 'to turn off any existing autofilters
        .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Amaysim - Woolworths"

        Dim rChange As Range, rCellChange As Range
        Set rChange = Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1), .Cells(1, 3).EntireColumn).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        For Each rCellChange In rChange

            rCellChange.Value = rCellChange.Value & "."

        Next

        .UsedRange.AutoFilter

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You're awesome ! Where did you learned how to create such amazing vba code ? :)

Comment: @Samayoa - I don't know how awesome the code is, but I have been writing VBA for close to 15 years, so experience is the greatest teacher. (SO has been a great teacher, too).